# Analyze data to find which parameters influence the most a scoring

Tags: data-analysis, correlation

I collected a dataset that looks like this

- P stands for parameter
- S stands for score

  ```
   1. P1_1, P1_2, P1_3 P1_N, P2_1, P2_2, P2_3, P2_N, S1, S2
   2. P1_1, P1_2, P1_3 P1_N, P2_1, P2_2, P2_3, P2_N, S1, S2
   3. P1_1, P1_2, P1_3 P1_N, P2_1, P2_2, P2_3, P2_N, S1, S2
   4. P1_1, P1_2, P1_3 P1_N, P2_1, P2_2, P2_3, P2_N, S1, S2
    ...
  ```

Each line is a "scene"

For each scene, I have a set of parameters for two different devices

- P1_i is the ith parameter of a picture taken with device 1
- P2_i is the ith parameter of a picture taken with device 2

For each scene I also have the score obtained with the two devices

- S1 is the score of the device 1 having P1_1 to P1_N for that scene
- S2 is the score of the device 1 having P2_1 to P2_N for that scene

Can you suggest me a method to find out what are the most impactful parameters responsible for the difference in scoring between the device 1 and device 2?

I would like to establish something like "when P1_7 and P2_7 are very different between each other, it has severe consequences on the difference between S1 and S2", while "When P1_3 and P2_3 are very different between each other, there is no significant impact with the difference between the two scores.

Would be also helpful to know if this can be generalized when the device are 3 (or n) instead of 2